# Using SQL to pull newest ID tied to client only

Tags: sql, sorting, date

I'm trying to pull only the Source_IDs tied to each Source. I currently use the following query which pulls all IDs

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client, Source,
CAST(Source_ID AS bigint) AS Source_ID, date_added
FROM table1
WHERE client in ('2020937')
AND TRIM(SOURCE) IN ('A','B')
ORDER BY Client
```

The results for this are:

```
Client  Source  Source_ID  date_added
2020937 B        9718352    20161004
2020937 B        22350540   20180601
2020937 B        9718352    20190402
2020937 B        11324740   20190502
2020937 B        9718352    20170704
2020937 A        890820888  20160714
2020937 B        9718352    20181002
2020937 B        9718352    20160810
2020937 B        11324740   20161004
2020937 B        9718352    20171002
```

And, in theory, I just want the following results:

```
Client  Source  Source_ID  date_added
2020937 A        890820888  20160714
2020937 B        11324740   20190502
```

I've been reviewing similar questions I've found on here and every time I think I've done it right, my query returns no results. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client, Source,
CAST(source_ID AS bigint) AS Source_ID, date_added
FROM table1 AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT Source, MAX(date_added) as NEWEST
FROM table1
GROUP BY Source) AS B on A.Source = B.Source
and A.date_added = B.Newest
WHERE A.Client IN ('2020937')
AND TRIM(B.Source) IN ('A','B')
ORDER BY client
```

I've looked at this long enough to make my brain hurt and I really don't understand where it's gone wrong so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery or `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT Client, Source, CAST(Source_ID AS bigint) AS Source_ID, date_added,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client, Source ORDER BY date_added DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table1
      WHERE client in (2020937) ND
            TRIM(SOURCE) IN ('A', 'B')
     ) c
WHERE se1num = 1
ORDER BY Client
```

Comment: . . . I think you should also need `Source` in partition clause.